# How can I replace an entire Div element (with other elements in it) for a single image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

This is what I have in my .js file:

```
function starClick1() {
document.getElementById=("RatingStars").src="../images/Stars1"; 
}    
function starClick2() {
document.getElementById=("RatingStars").src="../images/Stars2"; 
}
function starClick3() {
document.getElementById=("RatingStars").src="../images/Stars3"; 
}
```

And in the .html file I put this:

```
<div id="RatingStars">
<img onmousemove="imageSwitch1()" onclick="starClick1()" onmouseout ="imageSwitchOut1()" id="star1" height="14px" src="../images/starWhite.png">
<img onmousemove="imageSwitch2()" onclick="starClick2()" onmouseout ="imageSwitchOut2()" id="star2" height="14px" src="../images/starWhite.png">
<img onmousemove="imageSwitch3()" onclick="starClick3()" onmouseout ="imageSwitchOut3()" id="star3" height="14px" src="../images/starWhite.png">
</div>
```

PS: The other Functions doesn't have anything to do with my question (I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replaceWith()` replaces the element with another element :

```
var otherElement = $('<img />', {src: 'image.png'});

$('#RatingStars').replaceWith(otherElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, doing it without jQuery:

```
elementToReplace.parent.replaceChild(elementToInsert, elementToReplace);
```